# Unable to access rest of D: drive partitions with dual booted Ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I am unable to access the rest of my D: drive while using my dual booted Ubuntu. It doesn't show in other locations and it just doesn't mount. keeps saying " not found in /etc/fstab". I realize that my C: drive is encrypted but I should be able to access my non encrypted D: drive as my Ubuntu partition is also in D:

Comment: C: and D: are probably single partitions in Windows, try the `lsblk` command in linux to "see what it can see". And what command were you using to try mounting it, that gives the error "not found in /etc/fstab"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide a mount point in order to mount a disc. The mount point can be any directory in your file system, but Ubuntu by default uses `/media/` for its mount points.

In its simplest form the `mount` command is:

```
mount Source Directory
```

Here `Source` is the device address of the disc to be mounted (eg `/dev/sda6`) and `Directory` is the mount point.

If you add an entry for the disc in `/etc/fstab` this has two effects:-

1. The disc is mounted automatically during the boot process.
2. The `mount` and `umount` commands do not need both the `Source` and `Directory` commands: either can be used, and the other is inferred from the `fstab` entry.

You can also use the GUI `Disks` program to see your disc layout and mount individual partitions. In this case a mount point is created automatically in `/media/UserName/`, where `UserName` is the currently logged-in user. You can also dismount discs that you have mounted with `Disks`, but not `fstab` entries.

[image: Disks layout]

This is a powerful utility and it's easy to use, but maybe too easy to use, as next to the **Mount** button is the **Delete** button, which will lose your partition. Use with care!

You should look at the manual pages, `man mount` and `man fstab`. There is also a `man gnome-disks` page, but this has little information: use the in-program help <kbd>F1</kbd> instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, i figure out that the issue was actually with bitlocker encryption on the drive that i was able to see with GUI disks